Is there a way to mark your application as "not a game" to prevent the GeForce Experience overlay from showing?
When creating a GPU-accelerated window, Nvidia's GeForce Experience likes to inject its overlay and notify users of this:

Is there a way to automatically indicate to this software that your program is not a game, and that this overlay is inappropriate to be turned on by default? In the case I'm interested in the GPU-accelerated window is created through the Rust crate winit, but I'm interested in a more general solution.
As an example, it appears that the LibreOffice software also suffers from this problem.

Note: I'm not asking how to turn off the overlay as a user, rather, I'm asking how to ensure as a developer my program does not trigger the overlay in the first place.

NGL if LibreOffice is having this issue, I suspect its not an easy fix.

@easleyfixed If it was an easy fix I wouldn't be asking here :) For what it's worth that thread I linked is from 2020, so perhaps they have found a solution in the meantime.

I mean have you found a single example of someone using their library and them not wanting to advertise its use despite the software not actually being a game?

@easleyfixed I'm not sure I understand the question.

Do you know if anyone has ever pulled this off before?  I mean obviously hence the question but I suspect NVIDIA built it into the launcher.

@easleyfixed I don't, but searching for it is incredibly hard as no matter my google-fu I only get results of users complaining rather than developers discussing the problem. For the record, the application in question does not use a "Nvidia library" whatsoever, it happens just by creating a GPU-accelerated window.

Thats what I meant, the accelerated window uses their driver library.  The only way I could think to even get around that it like find a way to force a full screen graphic up on top of it for x amount of time, not like that is a simple process, but if you can't block it from popping up, try thinking about other ways around the problem, such as hiding it somehow.

@easleyfixed I was hoping more for someone to elucidate a (possibly just poorly documented, or undocumented) feature by Nvidia to prevent this rather than extensive hacks, but we'll see what shows up.

I hope someone has an idea for you! Godspeed

This was bugging me too.
If you don't mind turning off the notification for every application.
Turn off
Settings > Notifications > Open/close in-game overlay
This will only turn off the notification, and it will do it for all applications. You'll still be able to use the overlay by hitting Alt+Z (or whatever you have your shortcut set to)

This is not what I asked. Please read the giant bolded text in my question.

This doesn't answer the question.
